# Gamma identities computations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, dirac-matrices

I got my BsC in Physics many years ago (18yrs) but at those times QFT was not covered during the career, only in Ph.D. courses. Now I'm studying it at my own during my free time using several books on the matter (Ryder, Zee, Srednicky) and I'm terribly slow as I'm not used to.

I'm trying to reproduce the following identity (using East Coast metrics: diag(1,1,1,-1),therefore $\left\{ \gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}\right\}=-2\eta^{\mu\nu}$:

$\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\gamma_{\mu}=-2\gamma^{\nu}$

however I can't get it and I don't know where is my mistake. What I did was:

$$\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\gamma_{\mu}=\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}\eta_{\mu\lambda}\gamma^{\lambda}=\eta_{\mu\lambda}\left[\frac{1}{2}(\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}+\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\mu})+\frac{1}{2}(\gamma^{\mu}\gamma^{\nu}-\gamma^{\nu}\gamma^{\mu})\right]\gamma^{\lambda}=-\eta_{\mu\lambda}\eta^{\mu\nu}\gamma^{\lambda}=-\delta_{\lambda}^{\nu}\gamma^{\lambda}=-\gamma^{\nu}$$

can anyone help kindly help me to figure out my mistake?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Where has the commutator gone after the third equality? Gamma matrices do not commute (this is obvious is you know how they are used to construct representations of the Lorentz algebra, $S^{\mu\nu}=\frac{i}{4}[\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu]\neq 0$!).

Comment: Thanks! @Charlieª

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices#Miscellaneous_identities) offers proofs of some identities like this one.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake has already been noted, so I'll show how to prove the result. Since$$\{ \gamma^\mu,\,\gamma^\nu\} =2\eta^{\mu\nu}I_4,$$$\gamma^\mu\gamma_\mu=\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\eta_{\mu\nu}=4I_4$ and $\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu\gamma_\mu=(2\eta^{\mu\nu}I_4-\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu)\gamma_\mu=-2\gamma^\nu$.